# Why is ScrollTopCommand not working?

Tags: ajax, 9, modal-dialogs

I have a node edit form which I submit via ajax and then opens a modal doing this:

```
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array_merge($form['actions']['submit'], [
    '#value' => t('Get quote'),
    '#ajax' => [
      'callback' => 'open_quote_modal',
      'event' => 'click',
    ]
  ]);
  $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
```

This works fine. In my ajax call from this submit I do the following to capture any errors from the node edit form:

```
function open_quote_modal($form, $form_state) {
  $response = new AjaxResponse();

  // Check that there werent any errors from the Quote form.
  if ($form_state->hasAnyErrors()) {
    $allMessages = \Drupal::messenger()->all();
    $allMessages['#type'] = 'status_messages';
    $html = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($allMessages);

    // Remove any old messages.
    $response->addCommand(new RemoveCommand('.messages'));
    // Add new messages.
    $response->addCommand(new AfterCommand('div[data-drupal-messages-fallback]', $html));
    // Scroll to top of page.
    $response->addCommand(new ScrollTopCommand('body'));

    return $response;
  }

  // If no errors - code here to show contents of modal
}
```

This also works perfectly, except for the ScrollTopCommand. My errors are shown at the top of the page but I am left at the bottom of the page. There are no js or php errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the `views/views.ajax` lib:

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'views/views.ajax';
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks. Odd this one command needs an extra library attached and nothing in the documentation: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/ajax-api/core-ajax-callback-commands about this. Of course nothing in the documentation about requiring the drupal.dialog.ajax library either. Likely would make sense for this to be moved into the core library. I have used modals with ScrollTop before and never added this; but guessing they have Views on those pages so it gets added from that.